# blackness at the top and bottom of the screen in flutter

Tags: flutter

The app has a black problem at the top and bottom of the screen, how can I solve this problem?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ip0wJ.png)

```
I tried this codes
 SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(
      const SystemUiOverlayStyle(statusBarColor: Colors.transparent)); 
This code didn't work
```

Comment: The image does not show any blackness to me? Looks like a full red background.

Comment: I feel like you maybe put an image with a red background over a container with a slightly darker red background? If that's the case maybe make sure these 2 reds are the same?

Answer (score 0):

```
await SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIMode(SystemUiMode.immersiveSticky);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can check this issue page
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/65632#issuecomment-714535817

in this issue page said, this method needs future delay,
please try under these codes.

```
Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 1)).then(
(value) => SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(SystemUiOverlayStyle(
      systemNavigationBarColor: backgroundColor,
      systemNavigationBarDividerColor: backgroundColor,
      systemNavigationBarIconBrightness: Brightness.light,
      statusBarColor: backgroundColor,
      statusBarBrightness: Brightness.light,
      statusBarIconBrightness: Brightness.light,
    )));
```

Answer (score -1):

Looks like container or image is fit to width and centered.

try to fit image

```
Image.network(
  'image.jpg',
   fit: BoxFit.cover, // or fit: BoxFit.fitHeight,
)
```

or if its container, use 'expanded' to fill container to screen

```
Expanded(
 child: Container(
   color: Colors.red,
 ),
),
```